# Integrate facebook request dialog inside drupal module!

Tags: 7, social-network

I am trying to insert the request dialog inside drupal block, can you please suggest me how to do this?

I mean, do i have to create any js file, etc etc.. because i have no clue on how to do this.

Thanks..

Comment: you can try check the [list of modules](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_multisitesearch/facebook?filters=drupal_core%3A103%20bs_project_sandbox%3A0%20ss_meta_type%3Amodule&text=facebook) and find a suitable on for your use case...

Comment: i know that, but they use fbml which is depreciated.. what i need is just a little help in how to integrate this part.. just to make it visible